# Analyze FK Constraints

Tags: vertica

I'm experiencing some difficulties with foreign key constraints. I have a table 'ADDR', whose FK constraints are:
[image: FK constraints]

I'm writing a UDF on Hive to analyze constraints for a target table, but I don't have any clue how to implement this.
I tried below sql script to analyze constraints FK4_ADDR, but it didn't returned empty because column CTRY_CD was also a foreign key referencing table CTRY_PSTL and CTRY. So is there any other ways to check FK integrity? Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

```
select
distinct
      SRC_SYS_CD,CTRY_CD,CTRY_SB_DVSN_CD
 from user.ADDR t
where t.src_sys_cd='123'
minus
select
distinct
      SRC_SYS_CD,CTRY_CD,CTRY_SB_DVSN_CD
 from user.CTRY_SB_DVSN t1
where t1.src_sys_cd='123'
```

Comment: Did you try [ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.2.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/VerticaFunctions/ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS.htm) ?

Comment: What's this have to do with Vertica if you're writing the UDF for Hive?

Comment: Thank you mauro and Kermit, what I'm trying to do is to implements ANALYZE_CONSTRAINTS function in Hive, because Hive do not have this function and our projects need it. I need to check table's constraints using SQL, and I have no clue if there's multiple foreign key.